# Why Elixir's MapSet becomes unordered after 32 elements?

Tags: set, elixir

```
iex> MapSet.new(1..32) |> Enum.to_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]

iex> MapSet.new(1..33) |> Enum.to_list
[11, 26, 15, 20, 17, 25, 13, 8, 7, 1, 32, 3, 6, 2, 33, 10, 9, 19, 14, 5, 18, 31,
 22, 29, 21, 27, 24, 30, 23, 28, 16, 4, 12]
```

Here's the [implementation](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.3.0/lib/elixir/lib/map_set.ex#L69) in Elixir 1.3

```
def new(enumerable) do
  map =
    enumerable
    |> Enum.to_list
    |> do_new([])

  %MapSet{map: map}
end

defp do_new([], acc) do
  acc
  |> :lists.reverse
  |> :maps.from_list
end

defp do_new([item | rest], acc) do
  do_new(rest, [{item, true} | acc])
end
```

Even though the order doesn't matter in a `MapSet`, but still wondering why a `MapSet` becomes unordered after 32 elements?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is not specific to `MapSet`, but the same thing happens with normal `Map` (`MapSet` uses `Map` under the hood):

```
iex(1)> for i <- Enum.shuffle(1..32), into: %{}, do: {i, i}
%{1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5, 6 => 6, 7 => 7, 8 => 8, 9 => 9,
  10 => 10, 11 => 11, 12 => 12, 13 => 13, 14 => 14, 15 => 15, 16 => 16,
  17 => 17, 18 => 18, 19 => 19, 20 => 20, 21 => 21, 22 => 22, 23 => 23,
  24 => 24, 25 => 25, 26 => 26, 27 => 27, 28 => 28, 29 => 29, 30 => 30,
  31 => 31, 32 => 32}
iex(2)> for i <- Enum.shuffle(1..33), into: %{}, do: {i, i}
%{11 => 11, 26 => 26, 15 => 15, 20 => 20, 17 => 17, 25 => 25, 13 => 13, 8 => 8,
  7 => 7, 1 => 1, 32 => 32, 3 => 3, 6 => 6, 2 => 2, 33 => 33, 10 => 10, 9 => 9,
  19 => 19, 14 => 14, 5 => 5, 18 => 18, 31 => 31, 22 => 22, 29 => 29, 21 => 21,
  27 => 27, 24 => 24, 30 => 30, 23 => 23, 28 => 28, 16 => 16, 4 => 4, 12 => 12}
```

This is because (most likely as an optimization) Erlang stores Maps of size upto `MAP_SMALL_MAP_LIMIT` as a [sorted by key](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/1dbfc5fdc7dfecd69bb7e8a86fbadc844c5ffa58/erts/emulator/beam/erl_map.c#L1809-L1817) [array](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/1dbfc5fdc7dfecd69bb7e8a86fbadc844c5ffa58/erts/emulator/beam/erl_map.h#L38-L42). Only after the size is greater than `MAP_SMALL_MAP_LIMIT` Erlang switches to storing the data in a [Hash Array Mapped Trie like data structure](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/1dbfc5fdc7dfecd69bb7e8a86fbadc844c5ffa58/erts/emulator/beam/erl_map.c#L20-L21). In non-debug mode Erlang, `MAP_SMALL_MAP_LIMIT` is [defined to be 32](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/1dbfc5fdc7dfecd69bb7e8a86fbadc844c5ffa58/erts/emulator/beam/erl_map.h#L73-L77), so all maps with length upto 32 should print in sorted order. Note that this is an implementation detail as far as I know, and you should not rely on this behavior; they may change the value of the constant in the future or switch to a completely different algorithm if it's more performant.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!