# Elixir: How to get last n items in a list?

Tags: elixir

I have a list:

```
a = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,88,88]
```

In Python,  it's simple to get last n items:

```
a[-n:]
```

Whats equivalent in Elixir?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use [`Enum.take/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#take/2) with a negative value:

```
iex(1)> list = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 88, 88]
iex(2)> Enum.take(list, -4) |> IO.inspect(charlists: :as_lists)
[9, 9, 88, 88]
```

> **take(enumerable, count)**
>
> [...] `count` must be an integer. If a negative `count` is given, the last `count` values will be taken. [...]

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this method for very long lists. It will increase in time the longer the lists gets if you are grabbing values from the end.

Comment: @mjwrazor is there a better way?

Comment: use MapSet, [timing](https://gist.github.com/lexmag/32977ce8fd7cb44ddefa) `list = MapSet.new([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 88, 88]) |> Enum.take(-4)`. For normal size Lists that is fine but If you have a list that is like 10 million items use MapSet.

Comment: MapSets aren't ordered so this wouldn't work. Also I'm pretty sure just _creating_ a MapSet will be slower than my code.

Comment: They are ordered? I just tried in iex. Although they do not support duplicates. Well the point wouldn't be to create a map set it would be already be working with a MapSet.

Comment: They aren't. Try creating a large MapSet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38387520/320615. Even for small MapSets, they're sorted, not ordered in the same order as the input list.

Comment: Oh man. Well there are two other options, `Enum.slice(list,-1,length)` which I am pretty sure traverses. Or, `Enum.drop(list, length - 1)` Which I think might do the trick.

Comment: The presented solution is the optimal solution. BEAM VM implements lists as a linked list structure (http://beam-wisdoms.clau.se/en/latest/indepth-data-sizes.html), so the best solution will be O(n) where n is the list length.

Answer (score 11):

If you have very long lists, maybe you need to use another data type/data structure. There are many other solutions there are O(log n) instead O(n) for getting nth-tail of a list, for example: https://github.com/baryluk/ral