# Strange format of json response

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-poison

I have a Phoenix app which is basically API. I have the following view:

```
defmodule TattooBackend.Web.API.V1.AccountView do
  use TattooBackend.Web, :view

  alias TattooBackend.Repo

  def render("my_account.json", %{account: account}) do
    account = account |> Repo.preload(:studio)
    studio  = account.studio

    %{
      id: account.id,
      email: account.email,
      studio: %{
        id: account.studio.id,
        name: account.studio.name
      }
    }
  end
end
```

When I fire this endpoint in Postman it returns response in following format:

```
{
    "studio": {
        "name": "asdasdsadsa123123",
        "id": 4
    },
    "id": 1,
    "email": "chujbasd@o2.pl"
}
```

Why the "id" and "email" are last? They should be first...

Comment: Maps are unordered in Elixir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386314/why-elixirs-mapset-becomes-unordered-after-32-elements

Comment: They are not ordered in JS either, where JSON is coming from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Awesome email in the snippet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not guaranteed a return order and really, that's okay. If the order of those values matters then your consumer should probably handle ordering them in the way that it expects so that it's done correctly every time.

> Key-value pairs in a map do not follow any order

source: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html